# Audio drivers for Lenovo Z510

Tags: drivers, speakers

I just installed (Dual boot) Ubuntu 14.04 in my new lenovo Z510 ideapad which originally came with a windows 8.1. My JBL speakers don't seem to work as well as in windows. So I'm looking for linux drivers for the same. Tried to find it, but couldn't.

Comment: Having same problem here. Hoping for a solution.